# Exception while saving data in Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

**Exception** :

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'Audit_Log' because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the
>    element to support the current
>   operation.

I am using like that

```
Audit_LogEntity ale = new Audit_LogEntity();`

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
NetDataContractSerializer serialize = new NetDataContractSerializer();

serialize.Serialize(ms, obj);            

Audit_Log al = new Audit_Log();
al.Object = ms.ToArray();
al.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
al.Page_Name = pagename;
al.Pageid = uniqueid;
al.UserId = userid;

ale.AddToAudit_Log(al);

ale.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the Audit_LogEntity or Audit_Log rather than the saving process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to update the EntitySet - because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu)