# Entity Framework Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have a little problem. I am encountering the following error each time I try update my entityset.

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'ShoppingCart' because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no InsertFunction element exists in the
>   ModificationFunctionMapping element to support the current
>   operation.

The code is: `

```
public void AddItem(string cartID, string productID, string quantity)
        {
            using (CommerceEntities db = new CommerceEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    var myItem = (from c in db.ShoppingCarts
                                  where c.CartID == cartID &&
                                      c.ProductID == productID
                                  select c).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (myItem == null)
                    {
                        ShoppingCart cartadd = new ShoppingCart();
                        cartadd.CartID = cartID;
                        cartadd.Quantity = quantity;
                        cartadd.ProductID = productID;
                        cartadd.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                        db.ShoppingCarts.AddObject(cartadd);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myItem.Quantity += Convert.ToInt32(quantity);
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    throw new Exception("ERROR: Unable to Add Item to Cart - " +exp.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

`

Please help me. I can provide more information if required, I am new to this Entity Framework Model and following the tutorial on [This page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks/tailspin-spyworks-part-5).

Update: I added primary keys and redesigned the whole database. Now the error changed to:

> System.Data.UpdateException was unhandled by user code   Message=An
>   error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details.

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/220262bd-85d4-4f29-96a8-4a7d1d2c8293) might help you !!!

Comment: check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7583791/1551730) it may help

Comment: I added the primary keys on all tables and the problems is there as it is.

Comment: I have 5 columns in my table but I am modifying only 4 columns using the code above, Is that a problem?

Comment: and what's the inner exception?

Comment: @Karthik post it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens if entity set is mapped from database view, custom database query or if database table doesn't have primary key.