# Deleting Entity Object with 1 to Many Association to View-Based Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a Model-First entity model which contains a Customer table linked to a view that fetches customer details from a separate database. The relationship is One to Many between the Customer table and the View and I have a  navigation property on both the Customer entity and the View entity.

When I try to perform a delete using context.Customers.DeleteObject(cust) and call context.SaveChanges() I get an error:

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'ViewEntity' because it has a DefiningQuery and no [DeleteFunction] element exists  element to support the current operation.

---

I have tried setting On Delete Cascade and None and both generate the same error.

EDIT: There's not much code to show, but here you go:

```
Customer selectedCust = (Customer)dgvCustomers.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
if (selectedCust != null)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Are you sure you want to delete Customer {0}?", selectedCust.CustomerID.ToString()), 
                            "Customer Delete Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // TODO - Fix this
        this.ReportSchedDBContext.Customers.DeleteObject(selectedCust);
        this.ReportSchedDBContext.SaveChanges();                      
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your code bro

Comment: Does your Entity and table have a primary key?

Comment: The entity based on a real table (Customer) does, the view-based entity does not since it's based on a View.

Comment: Have you tried Remove instead of DeleteObject? Other than that hard to tell what's going on without seeing code of the context portions involved.

Comment: Can you show the definitions (or diagram at least) of both your Customer table and that view?

Comment: Is it a self-tracking entity? You normally should follow such a pattern as retrieve the entity from db, mark as delete and save.

Comment: I assume this is database first? It would help to see the essential part of the edmx diagram. You say the view entity doesn't have a primary key. It does. EF must have inferred a primary key, but not necessarily the correct one. This *may* cause trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by creating a dummy Stored Procedure that does nothing ("SELECT 'Done'") and using the SP Function Mapping in my two Views to set the Delete function to this Stored Procedure. Quite a hack but it worked.

I'm not sure why a Delete Function is required for a View or if I'm doing something else wrong which caused the issue, but the above worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Many related posts in SO agree with @Overmachine... you are probably missing a primary key on your entity/table.

See..

[because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322894/because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-insertfunction-element-exists-in-the-mo)

and

[Unable to update the EntitySet - because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu?rq=1)

---

**EDIT**

Just saw your comment regarding your `Customer` table having a primary key but your view not. Not sure whats going on without more of your code, but ultimately all you need is a `Customer` object with the primary key(s) set on it, then you can use the following code to delete a detached entity object.

```
this.ReportSchedDBContext.Entry(selectedCust).State = EntityState.Deleted;
this.ReportSchedDBContext.SaveChanges();
```

If you are casting from another type and that is causing problems, you could also do:

```
var cust = new Customer { CustomerID = selectedCust.CustomerID };
this.ReportSchedDBContext.Entry(cust).State = EntityState.Deleted;
this.ReportSchedDBContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your help. I forgot to clarify that I'm on an older version of EF (v4), so most of what you posted doesn't apply to me (eg DBContext). I tried updating my version but a lot of things broke and I don't have time to tackle this now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use of all foreign keys in View. when you use all foreign keys and primary keys in view you can update and delete object as cascade.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I didn't *want* do delete anything in the View. In fact I disabled Delete Cascade and I was still getting the same error. I had to basically define a dummy Delete Function with a Stored Procedure that does nothing and link the delete to the view for the logic to work.