# db.SaveChange(); is not working

Tags: entity-framework-5

I want to insert My data into my table named as 'Inward'
controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Create(Inward i)
    {
         if(Model.IsValid)
         {
           db.Inward.Add(i);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
          }
```

This Code Is Showing Error When Control Comes To db.SaveChange() Mathod;
And It Is Showing Error AS:

```
  Unable to update the EntitySet 'Inward' because
  it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> 
element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> 
element to support the current operation.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to update the EntitySet - because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu)

Comment: can you show the Inward model definition?