# Problems with updating Views in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

For some reasons we need to update `Views` inside the `Entity Framework`.
So we followed this [solution on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu/21768789#21768789) and it worked like a charm!

**BUT** here is the problem:
if we update our model (for some new fields or tables/views) the complete Mappings are destroyed and after updating we get the Warning

> Error 11007: Entity type 'UpdateView1' is not mapped.

After this it's not even possible to load the entities because all Mappings are lost.
So how to design the views to be able to post updates using the Views AND to be able to update the edmx file?

Comment: MS doesn't even like edmx files.  They are dropping it from EF moving forward.  Switch to Code First.

Comment: It's not possible to use Code First, the database is really old and really big...

Comment: What do you mean for "Model"? Are you trying to add a column to db, the reload, then update the class?

Comment: That's a common misconception due to the feature name.  Code First doesn't mean you have to start with code.  You can start with the database and then write your POCOs to match it (as in your case).  Doing so allows you to preserve all your mappings and such because you just adjust your code to match the structure already present in your database.

Comment: @FDL yes exactly, from time to time it's possible that we need new fields in the database. When we then upate the Model/edmx-File, all Mappings get lost.

Comment: @SamAxe you are right, if this works i misunderstood the Code First approach. I will have a look at this!

Comment: What happens if you delete the Table/View and then update the model from the database? Does it re-create the Entity?

Comment: @SamAxe If you post your Comment as an answer, i will accept it! Helped me a lot, thank you!

Comment: @OblTobl: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS is dropping support for EDMX files going forward in Entity Framework - in part due to the difficulty of keeping the database, EDMX, and POCOs all sync'd, as you are experiencing.  (Anyone can edit any of the 3, then changes are lost when a sync is done).

So they recommend using the Code First approach.  Code First is a bit of a misnomer and causes some confusion.

Code First doesn't mean you have to start with code.
You can start with the database and then write your POCOs to match it (as in your case). Doing so allows you to preserve all your mappings and such because you just adjust your code to match the structure already present in your database.

Another misconception is that you have to use *migrations*.  You do not.  You are welcome to not enable migrations and manually edit both the database schema and POCOs as long as you ensure they remain in sync.