# Getting error while inserting the data into table "Unable to update the EntitySet "

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to save the data in the database. Table name is `product_color`.

```
public void PostAddColour1()
{
     product_color pc = new product_color();
     pc.id = 999;
     pc.product_id=2;
     pc.color_id=1;
     pc.display_order=3;
     db.product_color.Add(pc);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is the function code to insert the data into table.

when `db.SaveChanges();` is called the below error shows:

```
Unable to update the EntitySet 'product_color' because it has a
DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the 
ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
```

Comment: Does your Table 'product_color' have Primary Key ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to update the EntitySet - because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have not defined any primary key on your table. When a table doesn't have a PK then the Entity Framework considers it to be a **View** and **not a table** and hence it doesn't allow data to be directly inserted to it.

Simply set a Primary Key on the table. That should do the trick

You can read more on this [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/entity-framework-error-on-savechanges1)