# Insert data into SQL Server in Entitiy Framework model

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

[image]

My code only lists what the database has at the moment, but I need to insert data into it.

```cs
namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Table_1> Get() 
        {
            using (testEntities entities = new testEntities())
            {
                Table_1 us = new Table_1() { id = "221", name = "asdsadasdsad" };
                entities.Table_1.Add(us);
                entities.SaveChangesAsync();

                return entities.Table_1.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

normally db updates with that query

```sql
Insert into Table_1 values ('111','222')

id (string)
name(string)
```

Comment: it gives valdation exception

Comment: Please provide the **complete and exact** exception (including all `.InnerException`  and `.Errors` details)

Comment: +  e {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."} System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException

Comment: +  e.EntityValidationErrors Count = 1 System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult> {System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult>}

Comment: And what do these `EntityValidationErrors` tell you??

Comment: +  entities {ClassLibrary1.testEntities} ClassLibrary1.testEntities
+  entities.Table_1 "System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[ClassLibrary1.Table_1]" System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ClassLibrary1.Table_1>
+  this {WebApplication5.Controllers.DefaultController} WebApplication5.Controllers.DefaultController
+  us {ClassLibrary1.Table_1} ClassLibrary1.Table_1

Comment: i have updated the questinon with error screenshot

Comment: We still haven't seen what is actually mentioned in the `EntityValidationErrors` - that's where EF would **tell you** in clear text English what the problem is ......

Comment: how can i find that where

Comment: i think the string length is more then 10 letters it givers an error. but its a nvarchar max?

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'Unable to update the EntitySet 'Table_1' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.'

Comment: See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu) about exactly this error message - any chance one of these three things in the accepted answer applies here? Is `Table_1` a **view**, by any chance? Or doesn't have a **primary key**??

Comment: ok fixed created PK. and regenerated the model now worls i can insert into db what about select,update and delete

Comment: Tables in EF (and in general) always should have a primary key - and once you have that, EF can do everything with the data in the table - all operations should work just fine, once your table has a PK

Comment: yes, now how can i pass a paramter into name       [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Table_1> Get() {
            using (testEntities2 entities = new testEntities2())
            {
                Table_1 us = new Table_1()
                { id=0, name="{name}"};
                entities.Table_1.Add(us);
               
                    entities.SaveChanges();
 

                return entities.Table_1.ToList();


            }

Comment: This is a totally different thing --> put that into a new question!

Answer (score 0):

Please use a try-catch block and find the validation error that cause above error.

```
try
{
    using (testEntities entities = new testEntities())
    {
        using (testEntities entities = new testEntities())
        {
            Table_1 us = new Table_1() { id = "221", name = "asdsadasdsad" };
            entities.Table_1.Add(us);
            entities.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entities.Table_1.ToList();
        }
    }

}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var ve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var err in ve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property Name: \"{0}\", Error Message: \"{1}\"", err.PropertyName, err.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    throw;
}
```