# exception in dbContext save changes

Tags: exception, dbcontext, savechanges

i am continously get exception in dbContext save changes line? my data enters through sql 2012 but not from visual studio? anyone can help me how can i handle or remove this exception?

```
try
{
    using (entity = new ShelfEntities())
    {
        bookTable book = new bookTable();

        book.BookName = textBookName.Text;
        book.BookAuthor = textBookAuthor.Text;
        book.BookPrice = Convert.ToInt32(textBookPrice.Text);

        entity.bookTables.Add(book);
        entity.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("successfull");
        listBook.Items.Clear();
        listBook.Items.AddRange(entity.bookTables.Select(x => x.BookName).ToArray());
    }
}
catch (Exception y)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + y);
}
```

Comment: wich exception did you got?

Comment: @timguy System.Data.Entity.Infrasructure.DbUpdateExcpetion: Unable to update Entity set ‘book’ because it has a defining query and no <insert function> elements exists in the <ModidfiationFunctionMapping> elements to support the current operaion

Answer (score 0):

I just googled you exception. This is what you should do first:

So check for this: [Unable to update the EntitySet - because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu)

> It usually happens because one of the following reasons:
>
> ```
> Entity Set is mapped from Database view
> A custom Database query
> Database table doesn't have a primary key
> ```
>
> After doing so, you may still need to update in the Entity Framework
>   designer (or alternatively delete the entity and then add it) before
>   you stop getting the error.