# Getting 500 (Internal Server Error) while inserting data using ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP .NET crud operations by following YouTube tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qIYBgWTlTo&t=232s). I am facing a problem of 500 internal error. Pictures are attached for the error. Whenever I click on Submit button I am getting error in console as displayed in a picture.[image][image]

[image][image]
I tried everything, even I downloaded the code from the link that was provided in video description but still I got same error. While running the code I am not getting any error in output window , don't know what is this scenario. GitHub repo of code: https://github.com/atif-dev/Asp.NETMVCCRUD

Comment: You need to find out what the actual error is. If you click the small arrow to the left of "POST", do you get any more details? If not, look in the Windows "Application" event log and see what information about the error is available there.

Comment: Attach to the server for that route and check what happens. Probably the server is running into an exception and the default error handling then sends a 500 response

Comment: @Andrew Morton I have edit the question for more details. And the server is running but I am not getting where is the issue.

Comment: @AtifIqbal Please post text as text - I can't copy-and-paste that error message into Google. But you can ;)

Comment: @Andrew Morton I have Googled the error "unable to update the entityset because it has a definingquery" and I found a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu but that didn't help me.